# SSIS Package deployment in production

Tags: ssis

I have created SSIS package and deployed in SQL Server 2008, and calling the package using ASP.NET which is different web server, when i load the package i am getting below error message.

package errMicrosoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsComException: An Integration Services class cannot be found. Make sure that Integration Services is correctly installed on the computer that is running the application. Also, make sure that the 64-bit version of Integration Services is installed if you are running a 64-bit application.        ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BA785E28-3D7B-47AE-A4F9-4784F61B598A} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application..ctor()

Below is my code that is used to execute the SSIS Package.

```
    Dim pkg As Package
    Dim app As Application
    Dim pkgResult As DTSExecResult


        app = New Application()
        pkg = app.LoadFromSqlServer("\\" & SSISPackageName, DB_ServerAddress, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        pkgResult = pkg.Execute()

        If (pkgResult = DTSExecResult.Failure) Then

            For Each local_DtsError As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError In pkg.Errors
                '' Logging Errors
            Next
        End If
```

In Web Server I have already installed "Integration Service", but still am getting error, can you please help if am missing any settings or runtime service to be installed in web server.

Comment: Your error message reads like you don't have the Integration Services Service installed on the target machine. Is it possible that you developed against 2008 and someone installed the 2005/2012/2014 version of integration services on the server?

Comment: I have installed SQL 2008 Integration Service on the target machine, but still am getting the same error.

Comment: Log on to the target machine and attempt to manually run an SSIS  package from the command line with dtexec.exe

Comment: yes, by running the package through command line the package is loading and executed perfectly, but why it is not working from the code?

Comment: Just covering all the bases here, is it possible that there are two SSIS installs on that machine and/or your code is targeting a set of binaries that are not there? How about the packages themselves, do they have a custom component that isn't installed on the server? Does every package fail or only a particular one? If you create the Hello World equivalent package, does that work?

Comment: hi all, it worked for me, on the target machine we need to install Integration Service as well Client SDK tool. thanks